# How can we use Feathers UI for developing Web and Desktop Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, web-applications, desktop-application

I found tutorials for developing Actionscript Mobile application using Feathers UI,Is it possible to do Actionscript web application and desktop application using Feathers UI?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. "Light-weight, skinnable, and extensible UI controls for both mobile and desktop applications."

Feathers is for use with the Starling 2D framework, so you will need to have an understanding of how to use that.

Whilst Feathers seems perhaps more targeted at AIR Mobile deployment, it can still be used to target Flash Player and deployed on the web.