# Feathers UI package to desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, mobile, starling-framework

I would like to know how to create a flash builder AIR project that can package a desktop app instead of a mobile app using [Feathers UI](http://feathersui.com/).

If i create an actionscript mobile project, as instructed by the FeathersUI getting started guide, i get the same component styling as can be seen on the Feathers live examples.

But if i create a 'regular' actionscript project, i get component styling which looks very small and not the same as on the Feathers examples.

What am i missing here? is it not possible to create a 'regular' actionscript project?
Then, using a mobile actionscript project, how to package for desktop?

related questions although not answering my question specifically:

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/feathers-ui-for-business-application-on-mobile-device-and-webdesktop-mode

[How can we use Feathers UI for developing Web and Desktop Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977271/how-can-we-use-feathers-ui-for-developing-web-and-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a desktop AIR app, you should use a desktop theme instead of the `MetalWorksMobileTheme` mentioned in the [Getting Started with Feathers tutorial](https://feathersui.com/help/getting-started.html). Feathers includes several example themes, and some target mobile and others target desktop. A good one to start with is `MetalWorksDesktopTheme`. It has a similar design to `MetalWorksMobileTheme`, but it's designed specifically for desktop.

There are two main reasons to use a desktop theme for a desktop app:

1. The same UI controls on desktop and mobile can behave very differently. A desktop theme will skin every UI control appropriately for a mouse-and-keyboard desktop environment and enable things like keyboard focus management.
2. The example mobile themes, including `MetalWorksMobileTheme`, attempt to resize their content based on `Capabilities.screenDPI` so that components render at the same physical size (in inches or centimeters) on all screens. This is great for mobile, but the components will be render too small on desktop, especially since the Flash runtimes on desktop don't report the proper DPI of the attached screen.

The workaround that you found by setting `DevicesCapabilities.dpi` isn't a recommended approach. This API exists only because it allows the demos on the feathersui.com website to simulate how the components would be displayed a mobile device. To scale a real application, you should use Starling's multi-resolution APIs instead. See [Multi-Resolution Development](http://manual.starling-framework.org/en/#_multi_resolution_development) in the Starling Manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find an answer to my question, by serendipity, here:

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/how-to-multi-platform-with-feathers-ui-like-example-of-feathers-on-website

It seems we have to 'imitate' mobile device settings for the FeathersUI to correctly display:

```
//pretends to be an iPhone Retina screen
DeviceCapabilities.dpi = 326;
DeviceCapabilities.screenPixelWidth = 960;
DeviceCapabilities.screenPixelHeight = 640;
```

as can be seen in the github source for the component explorer here:
https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/blob/master/examples/ComponentsExplorer/source/ComponentsExplorerWeb.as

Comment: This is not the correct approach. You should use a desktop theme instead of a mobile theme. Changing properties on DeviceCapabilities is a hack I needed to add to show demos of mobile apps in Flash Player on feathersui.com, and it is not recommended for real apps.

Comment: @joshtynjala I've always thought it was a bit of a hack and i should change it. However, it was a nice quick workaround to getting started with theme modification / styling :) - Oh and i have changed the answer also.